# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Can't open a connection

Tags: sql-server

I can't connect to the server once I stop it. I have no idea why it does this. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it which resolved the issue but now, after stopping it again I can't restart it.

There are 2 issues I'm having, one in the SQL Server Management Studio and one in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

SQL Server Configuration Manager has an error in the SQL Server Services part:

> The remote procedure call failed. [0x800706be]

I've looked this up and opened the ports, enabled tcp/ip, installed the service pack 2, also used the command prompt to repair the .mof files. This didn't clear up this issue.

SQL Server Management Studio will not let me connect to the database once I stop it. I've tried using `(local)`, `localhost`, `[computer name]\servername(default)`, `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`, and `.\SQLEXPRESS`

I'm at the end here, I'm not sure what else to try.

Errors In the Event Viewer:

".NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64) - Failed to compile: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtsinstall.exe . Error code = 0x800700d8"

and

"Faulting application name: wmiprvse.exe, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce79267
Faulting module name: svrenumapi100.dll, version: 2007.100.1600.22, time stamp: 0x4875405a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0003964f
Faulting process id: 0x598
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf40ec073a783e
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\sysWOW64\wbem\wmiprvse.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\svrenumapi100.dll
Report Id: 451c7b6f-acdf-11e3-909f-005056c00008"

Comment: I suppose something goes wrong when you try to **restart** the SQL server service. Check the [windows event log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) and post the error here...